# Can't delete a hidden file on a linux server

Tags: linux, ftp, lftp

I've a backups linux server where I upload my backups via lftp. I don't have any other way to access this server. For some reason I can't delete a hidden file.

```
$ls -la
drwxr-xr-x    2 100        ftpgroup            3 Mar 11  2021 .
drwxr-xr-x    3 100        ftpgroup            3 Mar 11  2021 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 100        ftpgroup    168215172 Feb  8  2021 .pureftpd-upload.601fd
```

I've tried following commands, but one worked.

```
$rm -rf .*
$glob -a rm -rf .*
```

I'm able to delete other files and folders on this server.

mv commands gives following error

```
mv: Access failed: 553 Prohibited file name
```

How do I delete this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FTP server looks like it's configured to block commands that refer to certain files, such as ones beginning with dots.

You can't do anything about it.  You'll need to contact the administrator of this server and ask them to delete the file or reconfigure the FTP server to allow you to do it.  If you have shell or SCP access then you might be able to do it.

Comment: It's a backup server provided by hosting company which I can access only via lftp from my web server.  No other way to access this server.

Comment: @Raymond Well, the answer is pretty clear then. You need to contact the hosting company. Pure-FTPd will not yet you delete the temporary files it creates.

Comment: Yes, you are right.